# Embedding video in UIWebView using iFrame

Tags: html, ios, iframe, youtube, uiwebview

I am trying to embed a youtube video in a `UIWebView`. However, the when I run the app, the page is **blank**.

Here's is my code for the embedding part.

```
NSString* tempDetailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"> <iframe src=\"%@\" width=\"%lf\" height=\"%lf\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe> </p>", videoURL, DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH, DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT];
```

The variables `videoURL`, `DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH`, and `DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT` have all been defined correctly.

For example, `videoURL` is `https://www.youtube.com/embed/CchqGSPNvns` and `DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH`, and `DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT` are `365.0` and `270.0` respectively.

Comment: How does the UIWebView frame? Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Give you my test of your question:

The result:

> [image]

My code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#define DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH 365.0
#define DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT 270.0


@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *videoURL = @"https://www.youtube.com/embed/CchqGSPNvns";

    NSString* tempDetailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p align='center'> <iframe src='%@' width='%lf' height='%lf' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe> </p>", videoURL, DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH, DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT];

    [_webView loadHTMLString:tempDetailString baseURL:nil];

}


@end
```

You can use `'` replace of `\"` in your `tempDetailString`.